# Get 'Specified class is an interface' while run the file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, service, interface, repository

I got this error while run the .sh file :

```
Error creating bean with name 'frdParameterRule2DAO' defined in class path resource [com/.../beans.xml]: 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [com.....dao.FrdParameterRule2DAO]: Specified class is an interface
```

This is the code that file .sh execute (I omitted unnecessary code) :

```
public final class FraudCacheBatchJob {
    private static final String CLASS_NAME = FraudCacheBatchJob.class.getCanonicalName();
    private static final String CONTEXT_XML_NAME = "/beans.xml";

    private static String getPackageLocation() {
        return FraudCacheBatchJob.class.getPackage().getName().replace(".", "/");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(getPackageLocation() + CONTEXT_XML_NAME);

            CachedRule cachedRule = context.getBean("cachedRule", CachedRule.class);

            cachedRule.getCacheRule2();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

`CachedRule` :

```
public interface CachedRule {
    void getCacheRule2();

    ...
}
```

`CachedRuleImpl` :

```
@Service("CachedRule")
public class CachedRuleImpl implements CachedRule {
    @Autowired
    FrdParameterRule2DAO frdParameterRule2DAO;

    @Cacheable(value = "ruleCache", key = "'cache-getFrdRule2'")
    public void getCacheRule2() {
        frdParameterRule2DAO.findAll();
    }

    ...
}
```

`FrdParameterRule2DAO` :

```
public interface FrdParameterRule2DAO extends JpaRepository<parameterRule, Long> {
    ...
}
```

`beans.xml` :

```
<bean id="frdParameterRule2DAO" class="com.....dao.FrdParameterRule2DAO"></bean>
<bean id="cachedRule" class="com.....spring.fraud.rule.CachedRuleImpl">
    <property name="frdParameterRule2DAO" ref="frdParameterRule2DAO" />
</bean>
```

While I tried to change the DAO to `public class`, I got error :

```
The type JpaRepository<FrdParameterRule2,Long> cannot be the superclass of FrdParameterRule2DAO; a superclass must be a class
```

What should I do? Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

I tried this (@StanislavL) :

`FrdParameterRule2DAO` :

```
@Repository
public interface FrdParameterRule2DAO extends JpaRepository<parameterRule, Long> {
    ...
}
```

`beans.xml` :

```
<!-- <bean id="frdParameterRule2DAO" class="com.....dao.FrdParameterRule2DAO"></bean> -->
<bean id="cachedRule" class="com.....spring.fraud.rule.CachedRuleImpl">
    <property name="frdParameterRule2DAO" ref="frdParameterRule2DAO" />
</bean>
```

but then get :

```
Error creating bean with name 'cachedRule' defined in class path resource [com/.../beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'frdParameterRule2DAO' while setting bean property 'frdParameterRule2DAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'frdParameterRule2DAO' is defined
```

Comment: Do not mix annotations and `xml` configuration. remove the lines from your beans.xml and activate `component-scan`

Comment: @Jens: Hi Jens, thanks, but can you elaborate a little bit more, pls?

Comment: add `<context:component-scan base-package="<your_package_name>" />
` to your context configuration. and remove the `bean` definition from beans.xml

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bean `id="frdParameterRule2DAO"` from xml and add

```
@Repository
FrdParameterRule2DAO frdParameterRule2DAO;
```

In you CachedRuleImpl instead.

One more thing

You have `interface FrdParameterRule2DAO extends JpaRepository<parameterRule, Long>` but expect list of another entities `List<FrdParameterRule2> result = frdParameterRule2DAO.findAll()`

Could be entity class difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion but I got this when I add `@repository` : `The annotation @Repository is disallowed for this location`. Sorry, I edited my question above, it should return nothing.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 `@Repository must be over `public interface FrdParameterRule2DAO  ...`

Comment: @StanislavL : If I remove `id="frdParameterRule2DAO" from xml and add `@Repository`, I get : `Error creating bean with name 'cachedRule' defined in class path resource [com/.../beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'frdParameterRule2DAO' while setting bean property 'frdParameterRule2DAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'frdParameterRule2DAO' is defined`